# gwtext.jar's version generated by gwt plugin of Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, gwt-ext

Currently I am using GWT 2.3.0 sdk and installed the google web toolkit plugin for eclipse.
I created a web application project with the plugin and want to use GWT-Ext.
Then, right click on the module (com.company.project) and choose "Google Web Toolkit" and choose "Configure for using GWT-Ext".
Then, a gwtext.jar is automatically generated in the project.

My question is, how can I verify the version of the automatic generated gwtext.jar and all the license issues with it?

Answer (score 0):

As I got you, you want to check the gwt version.

So follow this step.

Right click on the project->Properties->Google->Web Tool Kit.

After selecting Web ToolKit you can see the version which is in used and you can also configure the another version by clicking on the configure version.
Hope this will help you.